# How configure jenkins to get jenkinsfile from Team Concert repository?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm having a problem with Team Concert and Jenkins Pipeline script (*jenkinsfile*).

My projects are stored in RTC 5.0.2 SCM and the master instance of Jenkins downloads the whole workspace to get the Jenkinsfile. In the log I get the error message:

```
     Lightweight checkout support not available, falling back to full checkout.
```

I'm using **Jenkins v2.60.3** and **[teamconcert-plugin v1.2.0.3](https://plugins.jenkins.io/teamconcert)**.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

It's teamconcert-plugin limitation?

I know that RTC scm-tools (lscm) have a command to get only one file from repository. So, how do I configure Jenkins to use it to get pipeline script instead of teamconcert-plugin?

Thanks,

Esli Rocha

Comment: Is it working in a regular freestyle job ?

Comment: Yes. A freestyle job works fine with teamconcert-plugin.

Comment: can you share your pipeline ? maybe you need to add the scm-tools ?